# Resizing an image in iOS — undiagnosable leak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, uiimage

I have the following code picked from answers on StackOverflow:

```
+ (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    // UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 1.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

I am using this as a category for the `UIImage` type. I am profiling it in the following method:

```
+ (void)testResize:(UIImage *)image
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    int times = 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        // resize photo
        UIImage *resizedImage = [UIImage resizeImageToOptimalSize:image];
        resizedImage = nil;
    }
    double diff = (double)clock()-start;
    printf("testResize = %f\n", diff * 1000/times/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

It doesn't matter if I modify the above code and just dump the `resizeImageToOptimalSize` call 50 times, I see the profiler going nuts. Here is the `resizeImageToOptimalSize` code just in case you wonder I made a blunder here:

```
+ (UIImage *)resizeImageToOptimalSize:(UIImage *)image
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(..., ...);
    return [self resizeImage:image toSize:newSize];
}
```

The memory usage increases and goes up and then drops to ~ 1.5MB when the method finishes. Here is the instruments screenshot:

[image: Instruments screenshot for <code>resizePhoto</code> running on iPhone 4S]

There are no leaks per se from the Instruments tool but I don't believe it. It's either the for loop not letting go of `resizedImage` or if something's going on with the context (not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add @autoreleasepool inside the for loop.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    @autoreleasepool {
            // resize photo
            UIImage *resizedImage = [UIImage resizeImageToOptimalSize:image];
        }
    }
```

Also you don't need to set resizedImage to nil. Image is autoreleased(at least without optimizations).

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why I need to put this in a `autoreleasepool` block?

Comment: Image is returned as autoreleased object, but pool it's added doesn't have a chance to drain until function ends. You need to use autorelease pool in tight loops like this or rename method to something like newResizedImage so ARC returns "owned" object(there should be also qualifier for this, but I don't remember it).